# Bigint to Datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

How do I convert a bigint to datetime format in SQL?
Eg: 20130805092330 to 2013-08-05 09:23:30.000

Comment: That looks more like a concated datetime values than a bigint representation.

Comment: You have the option of using msdb.dbo.agent_datetime e.g. SELECT msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(LEFT([value], 8), RIGHT([value],6)), which seems the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't pretty but this is how I would approach this problem:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16),20130805092330),1,8) + ' ' + 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16),20130805092330),9,2) + ':' + 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16),20130805092330),11,2) + ':' + 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(16),20130805092330),13,2) AS DATETIME)
```

If anyone knows of a better way i'd like to know.

Answer (score 0):

Your bigint data not timestamp format, you can split bigint: 8 - 6 (date - time)
Try this:

```
DECLARE
    @bigint BIGINT = 20130805092330
    ,@datetime DATETIME
    ,@time TIME
SET @datetime = CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@bigint,8))

SET @time = CONVERT(TIME, LEFT(RIGHT(@bigint, 6), 2) + ':'
                            + LEFT(RIGHT(@bigint, 4), 2) + ':'
                            + RIGHT(@bigint, 2))
SET @datetime = @datetime + @time
SELECT @datetime
```

Result:

```
2013-08-05 09:23:30.000
```